# Do I need to create thumbnails for WinRT application

Tags: c#, image, performance, windows-runtime, image-gallery

I am coming from an asp.net background where if you want to display a photo gallery you have to have two files for each photo i.e. the original and a separate thumbnail file.

If I was to create a Win8App gallery that has say 100 photos per view. Would it be okay performance wise to simply change the size of the photo... i.e. only have the 1 file. (These are loaded from the file system).

I know it may depend on certain conditions but generally what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Depends on the file size, and where you get them from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the file size, and where you get them from. If the files are on the system you could use  StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync. Otherwise, if the files are large and you are getting them from somewhere else (a service) you could load them only as they scroll into view for the user. Make sure to dispose objects as you are not using them as bitmaps are notorious for eating up memory resources.

100 images doesn't sound like a lot for me, but it's better to have numbers to back that statement up with as I have no idea how large the files are.

Here are some [general guidelines for thumbnails from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/hh465350.aspx)

I would try different ways to deal with it and use the performance tools to see what the end result is. Maybe you could group the images and have the user view one group at the time, maybe use placeholder images, or maybe the files aren't that big and its no problem at all to simply resize depending on view.

For lazy loading (recommended with many items) use data virtualization by implementing the [ISupportIncrementalLoading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading.aspx)  You can [find more information about that on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx)